# How to append multiple columns of a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

I am trying to combine multiple columns of a dataframe in R into a single vector. What is the easiest way to do this?

My dataframe looks like:

```
X1    X2    X3     X4
----------------------
Paul  John  Cissy  Paul
Rob   Rob   Rob    Amanda
```

And the desired output is

```
X1
---
Paul
Rob
John
Rob
Cissy
Rob
Paul
Amanda
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try

```
data.frame(X1 = c(as.matrix(df)))
#      X1
#1   Paul
#2    Rob
#3   John
#4    Rob
#5  Cissy
#6    Rob
#7   Paul
#8 Amanda
```

Answer (score 3):

use `unlist`:

```
df <- data.frame(X1 = c("Paul","Rob"), X2 = c("John", "Rob"))
v <- unlist(df)
```

gives:

```
> str(v)

Factor w/ 3 levels "Paul","Rob","John": 1 2 3 2
- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "X11" "X12" "X21" "X22"
```

you can use `unname(v)` to remove the attribute names.

Answer (score 3):

One idea using `stack`

```
df5[] <- lapply(df5[], as.character) #make sure your columns are not factors
setNames(stack(df5)[1], 'X1')

#      X1
#1   Paul
#2    Rob
#3   John
#4    Rob
#5  Cissy
#6    Rob
#7   Paul
#8 Amanda
```